# can we add top to bottom slide in applications which are in full-screen mod in android

Tags: android, slider

I want to bring top to bottom slide in one of the activity of my application. My application is in full-screen mode. So is it possible to do without disturbing its full screen functionality.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I think SlidingDrawer is the answer to your question, not sure though. Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **Sliding Drawer** in Android to add top to bottom slide screen.

Have a look at [this](http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-slidingdrawer-example.html) example.

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Drag the control at the bottom"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:context=".SlidingDrawerActivity" />

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^" >
        </Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 1" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 2" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button 3" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class SlidingDrawerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 Button slideButton, b1, b2, b3;
 SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_drawer);
  slideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
  slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
  b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
  b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
  b1.setOnClickListener(this);
  b2.setOnClickListener(this);
  b3.setOnClickListener(this);
  slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDrawerOpened() {
    slideButton.setText("V");
   }
  });
  slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDrawerClosed() {
    slideButton.setText("^");
   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Button b = (Button) v;
  Toast.makeText(SlidingDrawerActivity.this,
    b.getText() + " is Clicked :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use sliderDrawer Layout from top to bottom**



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content" android:allowSingleTap="true"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/up" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sliding drawer example" />

    </RelativeLayout>


In your Activity

SlidingDrawer drawer;
Button button;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
drawer=(SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.handle);
drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down);
}
});
drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up);
}
});
}
```

Hope this would help you..:)

here is the link
http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/05/slidingdrawer-in-android-example.html

For more information about sliderDrawer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: thanks, this post helped me!

Comment: if this post help you,
then give +1 and acept the answer